# Is it necessary to webpack resources though with CDN available?

Tags: web, webpack, server

I am new to webpack , and recently i find it is even slower to webpack my Jquery and bootstrap resource into bundle.js compared to Jquery and Bootstrap  CDN loading method

Though webpack makes my Jquery or Bootstrap resource smaller and increase my web loading time , but  it it faster to use Jquery or Bootstrap CDN in my situation.

I think maybe my Linux server doesn't have nice performance.

To loading resource from my own ordinary server , use CDN to loading from public nicer server would be better if you don't have a good web server ,right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether one should bundle the commonly used libraries (like jquery, bootstrap, etc) would depend a lot on following factors (may not be a complete list):

Technically following two factors are key (may not be a complete list):

**Browser cache**: Browser tends to cache the files that a site uses so that site performance is better in subsequent uses. Although this depends on how the HTTP headers are set on JS file requests (Cache-control, No-cache, Etag, Expires, Pragma, etc), most sites do allow this caching in favaour of performance.

**Library size**: The larger the file, more time it takes to download, load, interpret, execute; remember JavaScript is an interpreted language.

Considering these factors, following are two approaches that come to my mind (broadly, not comprehensive):

**Popularity of library and CDN being used**: A popular library from a popular CDN is probably already being cached by browser when the user is browsing various different sites. Libraries on CDN are also heavily cached world wide. This will greatly improve your site performance.

**Tree shaking**: If tree shaking is performed while including libraries into bundle, it can greatly reduce the loading time because you bundle only those functions on libraries that you really use. If tree shaking is not used, the entire library will probably be loaded (as a part of bundle or separate). However, this is possible only when libraries are bundled. IMO, this is more useful when my application is small and use only a few functions from the library.

My explanation may not be perfect and comprehensive, but you can probably get the understanding that this depends a lot on which libraries you use, how it is being used in your application, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah, according to what you said , i should choose CDN rather than bundle in my own server ! great inspiration!

Comment: That solves your problem, you could upvote and mark as answer! :)